# IOS) Photo Extension Unable To Save Changes Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-extensions

I am making Photo Extension, but when I am trying to save changes(Done button Tapped).

> Alert Message Says "Unable to Save Changes" - 'An Error occurred
>   while saving. Please try again later.'

This is my code for
    **finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler**

```
- (void)finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(PHContentEditingOutput *))completionHandler {
    // Update UI to reflect that editing has finished and output is being rendered.

    // Render and provide output on a background queue.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Create editing output from the editing input.
        PHContentEditingOutput *output = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc] initWithContentEditingInput:self.input];
        NSURL *originalImageURL = self.input.fullSizeImageURL;
        //Apply filter
        CIFilter *appliedFilter = [CIFilter filterWithLUT:self.presetFilterNameArray[self.currentAppliedFilterIndex] originalLUT:@"LUT-ORG-512" dimension:64 alpha:self.filterAlphaSlider.value CIContext:self.ciContext];
        UIImage *filteredOriginalImage = [self filterApply:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:originalImageURL.path] filter:appliedFilter];
        //Apply orientation
        filteredOriginalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:filteredOriginalImage.CGImage scale:filteredOriginalImage.scale orientation:self.input.fullSizeImageOrientation];

        // Provide new adjustments and render output to given location.
        NSData *archiver = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.presetFilterNameArray[self.currentAppliedFilterIndex]];
        output.adjustmentData = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc] initWithFormatIdentifier:@"com.fantagram.BetterAndBetter.TKPhotoExtension" formatVersion:@"1.0" data:archiver];

        NSData *renderedJPEGData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(filteredOriginalImage, 1.0f);
        if([renderedJPEGData writeToURL:output.renderedContentURL atomically:YES]){
            NSLog(@"success to write");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"fail to write");
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", output);
        // Call completion handler to commit edit to Photos.
        completionHandler(output);

        // Clean up temporary files, etc.
    });
}
```

Previous Answer for this issue, someone said that when rendering to NSData, the size of image need to be different with originalImage. So I tried this, but didn't work.

One More Thing.

**Are there any way to open the host app from photo extension?**

> self.extensionContext openURL: didn't work(As I know of It only works
>   in Today Extension.)

```
UIResponder *responder = self;
        while(responder){
            if([responder respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:)]){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       [responder performSelector:@selector(openURL:) withObject:[NSURL URLWithString:(MY_URL_Schemes)]];     
                });
            }
            responder = [responder nextResponder];
        }
```

above code also didn't work. It worked when I used it `share extension`.

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your second question: It's in the documentation, but the iOS SDK's APIs that can be used from within an extension are limited. In particular, the whole `UIApplication` business is out of bounds (it makes sense: your extension is simply a shared framework being used by another app, which owns the `sharedInstance` of `UIApplication`). Thus, I don't think you can launch the container app from within the extension.

Comment: I created a minimal app based on Apple's sample code, except that it attempts to save the original image unchanged; the rest of `finishContentEditing:` is the same as Apple's code. I've logged all the properties of the `PHContentEditingInput` data passed when the editing session begins, and I soon noticed that saving always fails exactly when `fullSizeImageOrientation` has the value 6 (a.k.a `CGImagePropertyOrientation.right`), which somehow applies to all phtots I take in portrait orientation. As soon as I figure out a workaround or solution, I will post an. answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this,**

Go to SETTINGS then PHOTOS & CAMERA. I changed the options from Optimize iPhone Storage, to DOWNLOAD & KEEP ORIGINALS.

I think Normally under the Optimize setting photos are downloaded back to the original and then you are allowed to edit.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but the other published photo extension I downloaded from App store works well. I think it not a problem of iPhone Setting

Comment: I’m having the same issue. Some apps from the store experience it too, some don’t. Apple’s sample code also suffers from it. It seems to occur on specific photos.

Comment: @TKang I downloaded several extensions, as well as Apple's own sample code. Surprisingly, Apple's code and some of the third-party extensions (but not all) on the Store experience the issue as well, with some photos. A notably robust one, which seems to always be able to save successfully, is **BitCam**.